# DateTime represent how many bit in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, memory

Int, Float, Double, Decimal, DateTime .etc are value types. And I know:

```
Int:Represents a 32-bit signed integer.
Float:Represents a single-precision floating-point number(32-bit).
Double:Represents a double-precision floating-point number(64-bit).
...
```

But how many bit for DateTime? And why all value types in .NET are struct?

Comment: "And why all value types in .NET are struct?" --- that's not true. `42` is of a value type `int` and it's not a structure.

Comment: 42 is a struct indeed. You will find it when put you mouse on 42 in VS.

Comment: The .NET declarations you see for value types, like System.Int32, are indeed a *struct*.  It matches the type after it is boxed or serialized by BinaryFormatter, not something you ever observe directly.  The compiler, jitter and CLR have special knowledge of them, intended to make code fast.  Nothing special for DateTime, it is just a plain struct.  With only one field, it is UInt64.  62 bits of it store the date, two bits store Kind.  Ask only one question per post please.

Answer (score 14):

Based on [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx), DateTime represents 64-bit in C#:

> Prior to the .NET Framework version 2.0, the DateTime structure
> contains a 64-bit field composed of an unused 2-bit field concatenated
> with a private Ticks field, which is a 62-bit unsigned field that
> contains the number of ticks that represent the date and time. The
> value of the Ticks field can be obtained with the Ticks property.
>
> Starting with the .NET Framework 2.0, the DateTime structure contains
> a 64-bit field composed of a private Kind field concatenated with the
> Ticks field. The Kind field is a 2-bit field that indicates whether
> the DateTime structure represents a local time, a Coordinated
> Universal Time (UTC), or the time in an unspecified time zone. The
> Kind field is used when performing time conversions between time
> zones, but not for time comparisons or arithmetic. The value of the
> Kind field can be obtained with the Kind property.

Comment: was this answer usefull?